# ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement (50) != input nelement (100)

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I'm new to Pytorch so I tried to learn it by creating simple dogs vs cats classification.
The code:

```
class DogCatClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        print("1-st: ", x.shape)

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        print("2-nd: ", x.shape)

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))
        print("3-rd: ", x.shape)

        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        print("6-th: ", x.shape)

        x = self.fc2(x)  # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
        print("7-th: ", x.shape)

        x = F.sigmoid(x)
        print("8-th: ", x.shape)

        return x
```

I pass a single batch of data (data shape is (50, 1, 50, 50)

```
model = DogCatClassifier()

images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))

preds = model(images)
print(pred)

loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(preds, labels)
```

My prediction shape is (50, 2), so as I understand F.binary_cross_entropy(preds, labels) checks both predictions from a single image and that's why I get 100 predictions against 50 labels. Coming from tensorflow I thought that I could just implement the same logic like using sigmoid as last activation and binary_cross_entropy as loss function. What I don't understand is how to make this piece of code work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises because you are using binary cross entropy instead of regular cross entropy. As the name implies, it checks weather the label is correct or not thus the shape of both tensors (preds and labels in your code) should be the same. As you are giving the confidence of both classes, the BCE loss function gets confused and the code crashes. You can either do two things:

1- Change to F.cross_entropy(preds, label) as your loss function.

2- Change your code to pick the maximum value as the target.

```
  pred = pred.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True) # gets the max value
```

Let me know if this works, if it doesn't please update with the new error.

Comment: Changing to F..cross_entropy(preds, label) worked but for some reason when loss reaches about 0.65 it doesn't go down no matter how many epochs.
As for (2- Change your code to pick the maximum value as the target.) I get RuntimeError: _thnn_binary_cross_entropy_forward not supported on CUDAType for Long

Comment: The minimum of the cross entropy in Pytorch implementation is never 0. You can check this by yourself if you want by giving a copy of the same tensor. The important fact is that it has a global minimum. If your NN doesn't go below that it means that it has either reached the global minimum or that it is stuck on a local minimum. 

My advice would be to use schedulers in order to ensure that it jumps out of the local minimum. Or (easier) make it deeper by using more convolutional layers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. If I set momentum on my optimizer will it help?

Comment: As for solution number 2, I wrote that line from memory, it takes the maximum value, you should take the index of the maximum which will be either 0 or 1. I cannot search how to do that now, but google's got your back.

Comment: Yes, momentum will definitely help, if you are using SGD maybe try for something more complex like ADAM or RMSprop.

Comment: I tried using SGD with different momentums: 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, but loss, still for some reason, stays at 0.69. I checked that Adam doesn't have such parameter as momentum, but using Adam gave the same loss 0.65.

Comment: ADAM computes a momentum for every parameter of your network, it is a more advanced implementation. I would suggest using Data Augmentation to improve your results if you are not using it already. But this is outside the scope of your question. If my answer solved your problem, I'd be grateful if you accept it. Send me the link to a new question if you make it so I can answer your future problems.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm like 99.99% sure that I will have questions regarding Pytorch, for me it's very different from what I've learned from Tensorflow